# Как вывести ноды в Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, php

Каким образом можно вывести ноды только на заданной странице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - через пхп функцию выдернуть из базы данных (таблица nodes, по-моему ) 
Есть наверное красивые реализации через API но я с ними не знаком. Посмотрите в книге Джона Вандюка "CMS Drupal второе издание"

Answer (score 0):

1. Установить модуль [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/Views)
2. Создать страницу, задать URL и в фильтрах указать какие именно ноды выводить.

Полезные ссылки

- http://drupalguide.ru/articles/izuchaem-modul-views-drupal-7-uroven-12
- https://drupalize.me/videos/overview-views?p=1144